# Convert uploaded file to PDF

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a site that will (ideally for free) convert a file that I upload to a PDF?  Just general office formats, nothing fancy like CAD or other graphics formats.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google Docs is great for this.

You can upload a number of formats, and then edit the files etc.

When you're ready to get the PDF, just do File -> Download As -> PDF

Comment: I have found that google docs is very limited on it's surport for formating of spread sheets etc, so this is only likly to work when only simple formating is used.

Answer (score 3):

Adobe have an online tool for this under the Acrobat.com brand, there is a free plan if you want to try it out first

http://createpdf.adobe.com/

I've also used http://www.freefileconvert.com/ in the past to quickly convert files and have been happy with their service

Comment: It seems that Adobe doesn't have free plan anymore

Answer (score 0):

- [Free PDF Converter](http://www.freepdfconvert.com/)
- [Primo PDF Online](http://www.primopdf.com/online.aspx)
- [Express PDF](http://www.expresspdf.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Zamzar allows for conversion](http://www.zamzar.com/) of most (office) documents into other popular formats. Its free for filesizes upto 100MB

Answer (score 0):

My personal solution to the conversion question is to install a PDF printer like CutePDF (for Windows, such functionality is built-in to Mac OS X), set that printer as my default, then right-click and do a "Print" form the context menu in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the list:

- [PDF Online](http://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf/) - Word to PDF only
- [DocuPub](http://docupub.com/pdfconvert/)