# Is there a web app to convert .chm files to PDF in a readable format?

Tags: webapp-rec

I have tried Zamzar, which was the only one out of the many I tried that actually worked, however it created a barely readable PDF that centred all the text in the top left corner with almost no margins, and the text was not very readable - just not something I would want to read on my iPhone.

What would be awesome was something that tried to convert it into a readable format, more like a book - or something that was visually similar to webpages that have been processed into Arc90's Readability extension.

So if there is a web or Windows app that does this **well**, I would love to try it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert uploaded file to PDF](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/819/convert-uploaded-file-to-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Though not a web application, you could download a plugin such as [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/writer.asp) that enables you to print to PDF. In order to convert the entire document, you must select the highest level book, click print, and choose `Print the selected heading and all subtopics`. From there, I believe you can customize headers and footers to be added to the final PDF.