# Online PDF Creator/Editor

Tags: pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert uploaded file to PDF](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/819/convert-uploaded-file-to-pdf)

Is there any **free**, **open-source**, **online** PDF Creator/Editor which can convert a document/image of any dimensions(A4,A3..etc) into a PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few websites that can handle documents and convert to PDFs. However, while there are many open source PDF converter **applications**, I have not seen an open source PDF converter web sites. Here are a few of the free sites I've come across:

- [PDF Converter](http://www.freepdfconvert.com/) - per the site:

  > Convert Word, Excel, PowerPoint, Images, Web Pages and other files to PDF
- [Primo PDF Online](http://www.primopdf.com/online.aspx) - per the site:

  > PrimoPDF's free Web-based PDF converter, PrimoOnline, is the simple
  >   and fast way to create PDF files, online, without installing a thing.
  >   Just upload your file or enter a URL, provide your email address, and
  >   our server-based PDF creator will quickly convert it, and deliver the
  >   PDF straight to your inbox.
- [PDF Online](http://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf/) - Word to PDF only
- [DocuPub](http://docupub.com/pdfconvert/) - per the site:

  > Convert many of the file formats (doc, docx, xls, ppt..) that are used daily to PDF or Image.
- [Adobe CreatePDF](https://www.acrobat.com/createpdf/en/home.html) - per the site:

  > Just upload a file and create a PDF document with one click... [and] Upload two or more files. Get a single PDF file with the documents in the order you want to show them.